# How do I format bidirectional text inside a tooltip in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip, bidi

I need the tooltips in bootstrap to display a mixture of left-to-right and right-to-left languages; where the main direction should be right-to-left. For example, a tooltip content can be "`كلمة1 Word2 كلمة3 Word4 كلمة5`", and when displayed on screen, the words should appear from right to left as follows: كلمة1, then Word2, then كلمة3, etc.

I tried the following:

- The tooltip as plain text.
- The tooltip with html enabled via `data-html="true"` and the tooltip title is:

```html
<div style='justify-content:right; text-align:right; direction:rtl;'><p>كلمة1 Word2 كلمة3 Word4 كلمة5</p><div>
```

but it does not solve my problem. The above tooltip shows as: [image] in my machine.

How would I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is solved by making the tooltip title simply:

```html
<p dir='rtl';>كلمة1 Word2 كلمة3 Word4 كلمة5</p>
```